# Unable to create a form for Order and Contact

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a visualforce page and apex controller for an order from. When the user enters his details and click on submit, the code will check if a contact with those details exist in the org. If the contact is already there, the order will be associated with that user or else a new contact will be created. However, when the user is clicking submit, I am getting an error. Here is the code I have:

```
<apex:page standardController="Online_Orders__c" extensions="OnlineOrders" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

    <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
    <apex:form id="theForm">
     <apex:panelGrid columns="2" id="theGrid" width="40%" cellspacing="10px">

         <apex:outputText value="First Name" id="first"/>
         <apex:inputText id="firstname" value="{!firstName}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="Last Name" id="last"/>
         <apex:inputText id="lastname" value="{!Lastname}"/>
            <apex:outputText value="Email" id="email"/>
         <apex:inputText id="emailfield" value="{!email}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="Program Type" id="Program_Type"/>
         <apex:inputField id="ProgramType" value="{!onlineOrder.Program_Type__c}"/>
         <apex:outputText value="Price" id="price"/>
         <apex:outputPanel id="out">
          <apex:outputField id="Onlineprice" value="{!onlineOrder.Price__c}"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
          <apex:outputText value="Promo Code" id="promo"/>
         <apex:outputPanel id="out1">
          <apex:inputField id="promocode" value="{!onlineOrder.Promo_Code__c}"/>
          <button type="button" onclick="checkPromo()">Apply PromoCode</button>
         </apex:outputPanel>
         <apex:actionFunction name="checkPromo" action="{!checkPromo}" rerender="out"/>
         <apex:outputPanel id="out3">
          <button type="button" onclick="validatedetails()" style="padding: 4px;">Proceed</button>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel"/>
         </apex:outputPanel>

     </apex:panelGrid> 
        <apex:actionFunction name="submitForm" action="{!submit}"  rerender="out"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The apex Controller is:

```
public class OnlineOrders 
{
    public Online_Orders__c onlineOrder {get;set;}
    public String firstName {get;set;}
    public String Lastname {get;set;}
    public String email {get;set;}

    public OnlineOrders(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        onlineOrder=new Online_Orders__c();
    }
    public Pagereference cancel()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public Pagereference submit()
    {
        List<Contact> contactlist=[select id from Contact where firstname=:firstname and lastname=:Lastname and email=:email];
        if(contactlist.size()>0){
         onlineOrder.Contact__c=contactlist[0].id;
        }else{
            Contact con=new Contact(firstname=firstname,lastname=lastname,email=email);
            insert con;
            onlineOrder.Contact__c=con.id;
        }
        insert onlineOrder;
        return null;
    }
    public void checkPromo()
    {
        if(onlineOrder.Promo_Code__c=='Promocode1')
        {
            system.debug('###650###'+onlineOrder.Price__c);
            onlineOrder.Price__c=650;
        }
        else
        {
            system.debug('###750###'+onlineOrder.Price__c);
            onlineOrder.Price__c=750;        }
    }

}
```

Even though the test user is entering the first and last name, I am still getting the below error

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [First Name, Last Name]: [First Name, Last Name]
>   Error is in expression '{!submit}' in page onlineorders: Class.OnlineOrders.submit: line 26, column 1

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd be surprised but it's `!Lastname` on your vf page, but `lastname` in your controller.  Also put debugs in and see which one is null

Comment: Please use `system.debug` in your method and verify whether you are getting the desired values in the controller or not